# Remove duplicate rows from c# datatable using dataview.totable() not working for empty row values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to check existing datarows(**for all columns**) for possible duplicates in a datatable before adding a new row. Currently using the approach of adding a new datarow(using itemarray) to the table dt1 and comparing the row count of the existing table(dt1) and new table(dt1.dataview.totable(true)). However this does not seem to be working when the rows contain empty/null values

```
| Col1 | Col2 |
|------|------|
|Abc   |      |
|      |Xyz   |
```

When i try to add a new datarow - `(Abc, )`, it gets interpreted as a distinct row. Is there a way to handle such empty/null values using dataview.totable(), or linq approach to check if a row already exists(values of all columns need to be checked), or any other easier way? *the datatable columns get changed dynamically, so can't rely on column names

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, that tag was added mistakenly, I'm on version 7.x

Comment: So you want that a row where a field value is an empty string is treated same as a field where the value is `DBNull.Value`? If so, are multiple spaces also considered equal to null/empty?

Answer (score 0):

Gee, either always put in dbnull for a "", or always put in "" for dbnull.

If you don't adopt a set of HARD rules in your data, then coding this out will forevermore be a real pain. Computers and code HAS to have solid rules, and if you designs are well, sort of blank, but sort of null - the whole process becomes painful. This "long time" rule (be 100% defined in your rules) applies to all code - not just this example.

I think for this case? I would just "code right" though this problem if we going to ignore the above. (my choice would be always null - and use a data view against the table to filter and check in one operation.

However, due to the flip flop between "" and nulls?

Then just brute force code this out.

This works:

My table from SQL server:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, HotelName from tblHotels
```

Above is shoved into a data table - can have nulls.

So, now our code is thus this:

```
    object[] MySearch = new[] { txtFirst.Text, txtLast.Text, txtHotel.Text };

    bool bolFound = false;
    foreach (var MyRow in MyTable.Rows)
    {
        if (FindRow(MySearch, MyRow) == true)
        {
            bolFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    Response.Write("<h2>Results of search = " + bolFound.ToString() + "</h2>");
}

public bool FindRow(object[] MySearch, DataRow OneRow)
{
    object[] ar2;
    ar2 = OneRow.ItemArray;

    for (int i = 0; i <= Information.UBound(MySearch); i++)
    {
        if (Information.IsDBNull(ar2[i]))
        {
            if (MySearch[i] != "")
                return false;
        }
        else if (MySearch[i] != ar2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So, you just loop the rows - and your test converts any db null in the datatable to "". You ASSUME that your search array will ALWAYS use "" and not a dbnull in that array.

Above is less then pretty, but it not a huge amount of code.